# mongo-express pod does not start

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I started minikube with docker driver by minikube start command.
I created a deployment named mongo-express and a service for that.

mongo-express.yaml as below:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongo-express
  labels:
    app: mongo-express
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongo-express
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongo-express
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mongo-express
          image: mongo-express
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8081
          env:
            - name: ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mongodb-secret
                  key: mongo-root-username
            - name: ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mongodb-secret
                  key: mongo-root-password
            - name: ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: mongodb-configmap
                  key: database_url
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongo-express-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: mongo-express
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8081
      targetPort: 8081
      nodePort: 30000
```

mongo-configmap.yaml is as below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: mongodb-configmap
data:
  database_url: mongodb-service
```

and mongo.yaml is as below with service:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongodb-deployment
  labels:
    app: mongodb
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongodb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongodb
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mongodb
          image: mongo
          ports:
            - containerPort: 27017
          env:
            - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mongodb-secret
                  key: mongo-root-username
            - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mongodb-secret
                  key: mongo-root-password
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongodb-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: mongodb
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 27017
      targetPort: 27017
```

all pods starts and run without any problem except mongo-express pod. The mongo-express shows error as below and it cannot connect to mongodb:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the error above it seems your connection string is not correct.

Check [the official documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/connection-string/) that points out the standard URI connection scheme has the form:

```
mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,host2[:port2],...[,hostN[:portN]]][/[database][?options]]
```

In your case it should be similar to:

```
mongodb://admin:pass@mongodb-service:27017/
```

Comment: Thanks I will check, But in an youtube video I saw the connection can be done the way I did in kubernetes cluster using minikube. Maybe I have not generated username and password correctly.

Comment: I will have to use mongo-secret.yaml file with the encrypted username and password